How to integrate Bokeh panel dashboard with Flask
I have created a panel dashboard and I want to integrate it with a Flask app. I have had some success in doing so, but I encountered a problem. When a user logs out and reloads the panel dashboard, it does not appear and instead shows an error message.
RuntimeError: Models must be owned by only a single document, ImportedStyleSheet(id='p1007', ...) is already in a doc
500 GET /bkapp/autoload.js?bokeh-autoload-element=ff952a09-a902-4d77-91fb-1d058116d66c&bokeh-app-path=/bkapp&bokeh-absolute-url=http://localhost:5007/bkapp (::1) 549.87ms
while i run the code which as
`
# Bokeh application handler
def modify_doc(doc):
    dashboard = JiraDashboard()  # Instantiate your Panel dashboard or components
    pn_dashboard = pn.Column(  # Create a Panel layout
        pn.Row(dashboard.param, dashboard.update_charts),  # Add parameters and update controls
        dashboard.worklog_chart()  # Display the worklog chart
    )
    doc.add_root(pn_dashboard.get_root())

# Function to find an available port
def find_available_port(port):
    while True:
        try:
            with socket.create_connection(('localhost', port), timeout=1):
                port += 1
        except socket.error:
            return port

# Initialize Bokeh server with an available port
bk_server_port = find_available_port(5006)
bk_server = None
bk_worker_thread = None

def start_bokeh_server():
    global bk_server, bk_worker_thread
    bk_server = Server({'/bkapp': modify_doc}, io_loop=IOLoop(), port=bk_server_port, allow_websocket_origin=["localhost:5000","127.0.0.1:5000"])

    # Bokeh server worker
    def bk_worker():
        bk_server.start()
        bk_server.io_loop.start()

    bk_worker_thread = Thread(target=bk_worker)
    bk_worker_thread.daemon = True

@app.route('/dashboard')
def dashboard():
    if 'google_token' not in session:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))

    # Ensure that the Bokeh app is started on a separate thread
    if not bk_worker_thread.is_alive():
        bk_worker_thread.start()

    script = server_document(url=f'http://localhost:{bk_server_port}/bkapp')
    return render_template_string(f'''
        <!doctype html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <title>Dashboard</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Panel Dashboard</h1>
            {script}
            <a href="/logout"><button>Logout</button></a>
        </body>
        </html>
    ''')

def reload_dashboard():
    global bk_server, bk_worker_thread
    if bk_server:
        bk_server.io_loop.add_callback(bk_server.io_loop.stop)
        bk_worker_thread.join()
    start_bokeh_server()`

I try to close the broken session when the user logs out. I use the session_id for the broken session but did not see any positive impact.
